# Magento Order E-Mails Blank

Tags: magento

My Magento order confirmation emails are very hit and miss at the moment. Some will come up fine, some wont show the payment method and some are just blank.

The subject is always ok just the body.

Im currently on Magento ver. 1.9.1.0.

Im using a custom template for orders but its nothing complex.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}

                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 40px 30px 40px 30px;">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="color: #4d4d4d; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;">
                                            <h2 style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; font-size: 26px; font-weight: 300;">Thank you for your order from  {{var store.getFrontendName()}}</h2>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">
                                            <p style="line-height: 1.4em;">Once your package ships we will send an email with a link to track your order. Your order summary is below.</p>
                                            <p style="line-height: 1.4em;">Thank you again for your business.</p>
                                                                                    <p style="line-height: 1.4em;">VAT Number: GB902825341</p>
                                                                                    <p style="line-height: 1.4em;">Your contact email address: {{var order.customer_email}}</p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" height="22">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td bgcolor="#97cfd3
                                        " height="1">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" height="7">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="color: #4d4d4d; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;">
                                            <h2 style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; font-size: 26px; font-weight: 300;">{{var order.increment_id}}</h2>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">
                                            <p>Placed on {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}}</p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {{if order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
                                    <tr>
                                         <td>{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {{/if}}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                         {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td rowspan="2" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.4em;">
                                                        <p style="color: #4d4d4d; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">BILL TO:</p>
                                                        <p>{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                     {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                                                    <td rowspan="2" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.4em;">
                                                        <p style="color: #4d4d4d; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">SHIP TO:</p>
                                                        <p>{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}<p>
                                                    </td>

                                                    <td valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.4em;">
                                                        <p style="color: #4d4d4d; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">SHIPPING METHOD:</p>
                                                        <p>{{var order.shipping_description}}</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                    {{/depend}}
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td valign="top">
                                                        <p style="color: #4d4d4d; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">PAYMENT METHOD:</p>
                                                        <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.4em;">  {{var payment_html}}</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}
```

Comment: have you checked its preview?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tried with creating new order email template using System>Transactional Emails>Add New Template>Select New Order Template and create it.

After created it you can change style structure as your need. If still some email information not shows then enable template path hint and send order email manually and check if in phtml or block file something missing.